# Joda DateTime to Unix DateTime

Tags: java, jodatime, unix-timestamp

It's odd enough, but I didn't find any result about converting Joda(Time) `DateTime` to Unix DateTime (or timestamp, whichever is the correct name). How can I do this?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Any object that inherits from `BaseDateTime` (including `DateTime`) has the method

```
public long getMillis()
```

According to the [API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#getMillis%28%29) it:

> Gets the milliseconds of the datetime instant from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

So a working example to get the *seconds* would simply be:

```
new DateTime().getMillis() / 1000
```

For completeness, the definition of the [Unix Timestamp according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds.

You can also improve it further by removing the magic number division using the [TimeUnit API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#toSeconds(long)):

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(new DateTime().getMillis());
```

Comment: Suggested improvement to get rid of the constant. `      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(new DateTime().getMillis())`

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 added a new API for working with dates and times. With Java 8 you can use

```
long unixTimestamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
```

Comment: It is question about Joda DateTime, how is this relevant?

Comment: Yes it is, he uses and links to joda's `DateTime` in the answer.

Comment: Nice line of code. Has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: How does this answer have upvotes? Literally not an answer to the question.

Comment: it does the work

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Test
    public void covertDateTimeToEpoch() {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse("2020-07-09T04:30:45.781Z");
        long epochMilli = dateTime.toDate().toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        assertEquals(1594269045781L, epochMilli);
    }
```