# How to convert unix timestamp to local timestamp using joda DateTime?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I'm struggling with managing joda `DateTime` objects. What I need to do is to convert a timestamp of this format: `1459720800000` to another unix timestamp offset by the time zone difference and the daylight savings. I'm trying to use joda time for this but to no avail yet.

Both `new DateTime(millis, forTimeZone(timeZone)).toDate()`
and `new DateTime(millis, forTimeZone(timeZone)).getMillis()`
returns the original timestamp. How can I convert timestamps to different timezones using a `TimeZone` object? So for example if I have a GMT +0 date like this:

`Sun, 03 Apr 2016 22:00:00 GMT`
I would like to see

`Mon 04 Apr 2016 12:00:00 AM CEST GMT+2:00 DST`

when I use a GMT+2:00 `TimeZone`.

Comment: A unix epoche timestamp is by definition a UTC timestamp.

Comment: Sorry but this does not help me. I've never worked with TimeZones before.

Comment: Is your question about the millisecond value of the timestamp or the string representation of the timestamp, including the time zone information?

Comment: The reverse of what you want ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681348/joda-datetime-to-unix-datetime

Comment: About the millisecond representation. I'm trying to draw a chart and because of the daylight savings it gets shifted by 1 hour after the daylight saving started :(

Comment: The millisecond representation is always in UTC. UTC does not follow daylight savings time. So if you plot the milliseconds, you should not see any "timezone shifting". Or I am still not getting your question...

Comment: Then I simply does not understand this at all.

Comment: The two example string representations you gave in your question are the same point in time. So their unix epoche value (milliseconds since Jan 1st, 1970, UTC) is the same. The UTC time is continuous. There are no gaps or jumps due to daylight savings time because UTC does not have daylight savings time. So there cannot be any shifts if you are plotting the UTC millisecond timestamps.

Comment: But there is. I'm simply processing timestamps from a REST api and I can see the 1 hour jump in my chart.

Comment: Maybe the confusion is here: During standard time the timezone Europe/Berlin is UTC+1. During daylight savings time it is UTC+2. Assume this is the last millisecond before switching to daylight savings time: `2016-03-27T02:00:00.000+01:00`. The next millisecond in that timezone is `2016-03-27T03:00:00.001+02:00`.

Comment: What are you receiving on your REST API? A number representing milliseconds in unix epoche or a string representation like the ones you gave as an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108186/discussion-between-adam-arold-and-ralf).